# How to create dynamic HTML table in ASP.Net MVC (analog HtmlTable in webforms)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html-table

How to create dynamic table with the complex structure and different styles of cells?

I have a lot of code such as:

**In Controller:**

```
string styleTag = "class=\"someCssStyle\"";
ViewBag.htmlRawName1 += "<td colspan=\"" + colspan +
                    "\" " + styleTag + ">" + name + "</td>";
                for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++)
                {
                    ViewBag.htmlRawName2 += "<td " + styleTag + ">" + list[i].Name +
                        "</td>";
                }
```

**In View:**

```
<table>
   <tr>
       @Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlRawName1 )
   </tr>
   <tr>
       @Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlRawName2 )
   </tr>
</table>
```

Can I use HtmlHelper instead of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your data to the view in your controller action :

in your controller :

```
List<YourClass> viewModel = list;
ViewBag.NbColumns = 5; //Number of your table's columns
return View(list);
```

in your view :

```
@model List<YourClass>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="@ViewBag.NbColumns">Name</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    @foreach(var item in Model) {
        <td class="someCssStyle">@item.Name</td>
    }
  </tr>
<table>
```